# Druid spatialDimensions loading data error during Hadoop Ingestion

Tags: java, hadoop, druid, data-ingestion

- I have an hadoop ingestion process of a data (just like https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/hadoop.html)
- Current druid indexer version is **0.14.2-incubating**
- Data is a TSV files on GCS.

Previously used the old version of the druid indexer and there were no problems. After upgrading to a new version got an error.

*Some details*

Here is a parse section from my spec:

```
      "parser": {
        "parseSpec": {
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "spatialDimensions": [
              {
                "dimName": "geo",
                "dims": ["latitude", "longitude"]
              }
            ],
            "dimensionExclusions": [],
            "dimensions":[
              "ip_address",
              "radius",
              "confidence"
            ]
          },
          "timestampSpec": {
            "format": "millis",
            "column": "ts"
          },
          "columns": [
            "ts",
            "ip_address",
            "latitude",
            "longitude",
            "radius",
            "confidence"
          ],
          "format":"tsv"
        },
        "type": "lzo"
      }
    },
```

This section is lead to an error that looks:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.druid.cli.CliHadoopIndexer.run(CliHadoopIndexer.java:116)
    at org.apache.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DelimitedParseSpec] value failed: column[geo] not in columns. (through reference chain: org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.StringInputRowParser["parseSpec"])
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3459)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3378)
    at org.apache.druid.segment.indexing.DataSchema.getParser(DataSchema.java:126)
    at org.apache.druid.indexer.HadoopDruidIndexerConfig.verify(HadoopDruidIndexerConfig.java:591)
    at org.apache.druid.indexer.HadoopDruidIndexerJob.<init>(HadoopDruidIndexerJob.java:49)
    at org.apache.druid.cli.CliInternalHadoopIndexer.run(CliInternalHadoopIndexer.java:124)
    at org.apache.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:118)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DelimitedParseSpec] value failed: column[geo] not in columns. (through reference chain: org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.StringInputRowParser["parseSpec"])
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.wrapException(StdValueInstantiator.java:399)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:231)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:135)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:442)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1099)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:296)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:122)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:93)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:131)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:518)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:463)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:378)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1099)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:296)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:122)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:93)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:131)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3454)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column[geo] not in columns.
    at shade.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:148)
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DelimitedParseSpec.verify(DelimitedParseSpec.java:119)
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DelimitedParseSpec.<init>(DelimitedParseSpec.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:125)
    at shade.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromObjectWith(StdValueInstantiator.java:227)
    ... 33 more
```

I see that spec parser tries to locate dimension among columns, but it is spatial dimensions!

This is pretty painful issue that hit out production.
Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this error ?

Answer (score -1):

```
"parser": {
  "type": "string",
  "parseSpec": {
    "format": "json",
     "flattenSpec": {
          "fields": [
          { "type": "path", "name": "Longitude", "expr": "$.location.lon" },
           { "type": "path", "name": "Latitude", "expr": "$.location.lat" }
        ]
      },
    "timestampSpec": {
      "column": "timeStamp",
      "format": "auto"
    },
     "dimensionsSpec": {
      "dimensions": ["blogid", "category","eventType","userid" ],
        "spatialDimensions": [
    {
        "dimName": "coordinates",
        "dims": ["Latitude", "Longitude"]
    } 
                                    ]       
    }
    }       
  }
```

Comment: Please add some context/explanation around your answer